# Passing parameters in URL (python requests) and webscrape

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to web scrape this website http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_projects.aspx

how to use this website:
select any value from drop down and click search and you will see table.In table click by pressing ctrl on the view details. It opens into new window ,i trying to webscrape those links for every single drop down value

When i run the below code it scraps the website but gives me webiste url mentioned above not the links i am looking for

below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

final_data = []

url = "http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_projects.aspx"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")

VIEWSTATE = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

for title in soup.select("#ContentPlaceHolder1_DdlprojectDistrict [value]")[:-1]:
    search_item = title.text
    # print(search_item)
    headers= {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

    formfields = {'__VIEWSTATE':VIEWSTATE,  #Put the value in this variable
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'4F1A7E70',
                '__EVENTVALIDATION':EVENTVALIDATION, #Put the value in this variable
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DdlprojectDistrict':search_item, #this is where your city name changes in each iteration
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtProject':'',
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch':'Search'}

    #here in form details check agra , i am able to scrape one city only,
    # how to loop for all cities
    s=  requests.session()
    res = s.post(url, data=formfields, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
    VIEWSTATE = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    EVENTVALIDATION = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

    get_list  = soup.find_all('option')   #gets list of all <option> tag
    for element in get_list :
        cities = element["value"]
        #final.append(cities)
        #print(final)

    get_details = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"id":"ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"})

    for details in get_details:
        text = details.find_all("tr")[1:]
        count = 0
        for tds in text:
            td = tds.find_all("td")[1]
            rera = td.find_all("span")
            rnumber = ""
            for num in rera:
                rnumber = num.text
                sublist = []
                sublist.append(rnumber)
            name = tds.find_all("td")[2]
            prj_name = name.find_all("span")
            prj = ""
            for prjname in prj_name:
                prj = prjname.text
                sublist.append(prj)
            promoter_name = tds.find_all("td")[3]
            promoter = promoter_name.find_all("span")
            prom = ""
            for promname in promoter:
                prom = promname.text
                sublist.append(prom)
            district = tds.find_all("td")[4]
            dist = district.find_all("span")
            district_name = ""
            for districtname in dist:
                district_name = districtname.text
                sublist.append(district_name)
            project_type = tds.find_all("td")[5]
            project = project_type.find_all("span")
            btn_td = tds.find_all("td")[6]
            ip_name = btn_td.find("input").attrs['name']
            dct = {}
            dct['__VIEWSTATE']=VIEWSTATE
            dct['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']=formfields['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']
            dct['__EVENTVALIDATION']=EVENTVALIDATION
            dct['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtProject'] = ''
            dct['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DdlprojectDistrict'] = formfields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DdlprojectDistrict']
            dct[ip_name+'binid'] = '6869'
            dct[ip_name+'hfFlag'] = 'edit'
            dct[ip_name+'ddlPRJ'] = 'Agra'
            dct[ip_name+'txtPRJ'] = ''

            resp = s.post(url, data=dct, headers=headers)
            projectype = ""
            for prjtype in project:
                projectype = prjtype.text
                sublist.append(projectype)
            print( resp.url )
            sublist.append( resp.url )
            final_data.append(sublist)
            count += 1
            print(count)

filename = "UP_RERA.csv"
with open("./"+filename, "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0, len(final_data)):
        csvfile.writerow(final_data[i])
```

can anyone please help me in this.? I am parsing the correct urls

Comment: maybe use `session` at start - with `get()` too.

Comment: you shouldn't put `sublist = []` inside `for num in rera:`

Comment: all urls are create by JavaScript - but this url seems has the same schema `http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_Registration_Details.aspx?binid=10996&hfFlag=edit&ddlPRJ=Lucknow&txtPRJ=` There is `district` and digits from `rare` so you can generate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Urls are created by JavaScript - but those urls seems have the same schema

```
http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_Registration_Details.aspx?binid=10996&hfFlag=edit&ddlPRJ=Lucknow&txtPRJ=
```

There is `district` - `Lucknow` - and digits from `rare` - `10996` - so you can generate it manually.

---

Code with changes:

For test I use `if count > 3: break` to limit data on screen.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

final_data = []

url = "http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_projects.aspx"

s = requests.session()

response = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

VIEWSTATE = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

headers= {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

formfields = {
    '__VIEWSTATE': VIEWSTATE,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '4F1A7E70',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': EVENTVALIDATION,
    #'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DdlprojectDistrict': search_item,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtProject': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch': 'Search'
}

for title in soup.select("#ContentPlaceHolder1_DdlprojectDistrict [value]")[:-1]:
    search_item = title.text
    print('\n-----', search_item, '-----\n')

    formfields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DdlprojectDistrict'] = search_item

    response = s.post(url, data=formfields, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    all_options  = soup.find_all('option')
    for element in all_options:
        cities = element["value"]

    all_rows = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"}).find_all("tr")[1:]

    count = 0

    for row in all_rows:
        sublist = [search_item]

        tds = row.find_all("td")

        rera = tds[1].find("span").text
        sublist.append(rera)
        print('rera:', rera)

        name = tds[2].find("span").text
        sublist.append(name)
        print('name:', name)

        promoter_name = tds[3].find("span").text
        sublist.append(promoter_name)
        print('promoter_name:', promoter_name)

        district = tds[4].find("span").text
        sublist.append(district)
        print('district:', district)

        project_type = tds[5].find("span").text
        sublist.append(project_type)
        print('project_type:', project_type)

        rare_id = rera[9:]
        print('rare_id:', rare_id)
        details_url = 'http://uprera.azurewebsites.net/View_Registration_Details.aspx?binid={}&hfFlag=edit&ddlPRJ={}&txtPRJ='.format(rare_id, district)

        sublist.append(details_url)
        print('url:', details_url)

        final_data.append(sublist)

        count += 1
        print('count:', count)

        # for test exit after 10 results
        if count > 3: break


filename = "./UP_RERA.csv"
with open(filename, "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvfile.writerow(['search_item', 'rare', 'name', 'promoter_name', 'district', 'project_type', 'url'])
    for row in final_data:
        csvfile.writerow(row)
```